# Accessing web service by application name not bean name oracle 12c?

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, soap, weblogic

I have a webservice deployed on oracle weblogic 12c. The application name is `MyWebService`, and the service name is `CalculatorWS`, the EJB name is `CalculatorWSSessionEJBBean`.

The web service have been created with jdeveloper compatible with weblogic 11g.

On 11g, I can access the service through the application name as:

http://ipAddress:port/MyWebService/CalculatorWS?WSDL

On 12c, using the same deployment, I cannot access the web service through this URL, but with:

http://ipAddress:port/CalculatorWSSessionEJBBean/CalculatorWS?WSDL

**Bean Annotations**

```
@Stateless(name = "CalculatorWSSessionEJB", mappedName = "MyWebService")
@WebService( serviceName ="CalculatorWS")
// set the binding to use SOAP version 1.2
@BindingType(value="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/")
public class CalculatorWSSessionEJBBean
```

How can I consolidate the URL for both versions of weblogic?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could come up with was to change the main webservice class name to `MyWebService`, this way I got the same URL working for both versions.